# Locking help page list three exceptions of a permanent lock, but says that there are only 2

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, wording

In [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts)

> Permanent locks should almost never be used, with the exception of those imposed by the system itself. There are **two exceptions**:

But there are actually three listed in the ordered list. The straight up solution is to change two to three, other would be just mention that there are exceptions without number.

Comment: I'd go with "There are few exceptions:" to avoid this bug when adding/removing exceptions in the future...

Comment: @Shadow10YearsWizard personally, I worry about the exceptions creep. A rule book made up of exceptions would be of infinite length.